# Transform type of each array element using a transformer

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I am new to C# and I found a task that really confused me.

It's about making a method that takes an array and transforms its elements's types according to an existing `transformer` .

And I have no idea how to specficially use this existing transformer. It seems to be an interface, but I don't know how to apply it in that method since I usually would just use `ConvertAll` or some other simple way.

```
        public static class ArrayExtension
    {
        /// Transforms each element of source array from one type to another type by some rule.
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of source array.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the elements of result array.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source array.</param>
        /// <param name="transformer">A <see cref="ITransformer{TSource,TResult}"/> that defines the rule of transformation.</param>
        /// <returns>An array, each element of which is transformed.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when array or transformer is null.</exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown when array is empty.</exception>

        public static TResult[] Transform<TSource, TResult>(this TSource[] source, ITransformer<TSource, TResult> transformer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't that what LINQ's Select does? What transformer are you talking about?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can I use LINGQ Select in this context with ```transform```? Or do you mean that I can just use it without using transform?

Comment: I am really not sure what your question is or what you expect for an answer. I suppose you need to return some result of a call to  some method on the interface, which gets the source array as an input. But without seeing that interface, we cannot possibly say more.

Comment: @Akzhol what transform? What methods are you talking about? `Array.ConvertAll` uses a simple delegate, not any ITransform object. The only google result for `Transforms each element of source array from one type to another type` is a similar question from May 2022

Comment: Is this an exam question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, this is an assignment.
@Fildor I think the point of it is to use that interface to transform an array according to it. 
This is the only thing about this interface that I could find in the solution. 
   `public interface ITransformer<in TSource, out TResult> {  /// Represents a method that converts an object from one type to another type. /// <returns>The TResult that represents the converted TSource.</returns>
TResult Transform(TSource obj);
    } 
`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `ITransformer` has some method - let's assume it is called `Convert`; so ... just call that for each element. A lazy approach might be

```cs
return Array.ConvertAll(transformer.Convert);`
```

however, this is unnecessarily allocation heavy. A more frugal approach takes more typing:

```cs
if (source.Length == 0) return Array.Empty<TResult>();
var result = new TResult[source.Length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < source.Length ; i++)
{
    result[i] = transformer.Convert(source[i]);
}
return result;
```

Comment: That's homework. The exact same code appeared in May